# Image Filtering

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, image-processing, filter, uiimage

I have an application that requires some work on image filters, so I just started working on  filters and I achieved few filters like Black & white, Hud, moss,brightness,contrast etc.

Here are few filters that I am facing problem to achieve

1. Nostalgia
2. Vintage
3. Old

Original Image

[image]

Nostalgia

[image]

vintage

[image]

old

[image]

If anyone can guide me on the right direction it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11158-share-your-image-proccessing-filter-code.html) thread is very informative about image filtering in iphone...

## EDIT

This what I have done to make an image vintage (Vintage image requirement in my case was slightly different..It didn't have shades on the edges)

```
//first increase contrast a bit...
float contrastValue             =   1.45;
CGImageRef originalImage        =   [myImage CGImage];
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace      =   CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bitmapContext      =   CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,CGImageGetWidth(originalImage),CGImageGetHeight(originalImage),8,CGImageGetWidth(originalImage)*4,colorSpace,kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmapContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGBitmapContextGetWidth(bitmapContext), CGBitmapContextGetHeight(bitmapContext)), originalImage);
UInt8* data                     =   CGBitmapContextGetData(bitmapContext);
int numComponents               =   4;
int bytesInContext              =   CGBitmapContextGetHeight(bitmapContext) * CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(bitmapContext);
double redIn, greenIn, blueIn;

for (int i = 0; i < bytesInContext; i += numComponents) {
    redIn                       =   (double)data[i]/255.0;
    greenIn                     =   (double)data[i+1]/255.0;
    blueIn                      =   (double)data[i+2]/255.0;
    
    redIn                       -=  0.5;
    redIn                       *=  contrastValue;
    redIn                       +=  0.5;
    redIn                       *=  255.0;
    if (redIn < 0) {
        redIn                   =   0;
    }
    if (redIn > 255) {
        redIn                   =   255;
    }
    
    greenIn                     -=  0.5;
    greenIn                     *=  contrastValue;
    greenIn                     +=  0.5;
    greenIn                     *=  255.0;
    if (greenIn < 0) {
        greenIn                 =   0;
    }
    if (greenIn > 255) {
        greenIn                 =   255;
    }
    
    
    blueIn                      -=  0.5;
    blueIn                      *=  contrastValue;
    blueIn                      +=  0.5;
    blueIn                      *=  255.0;
    if (blueIn < 0) {
        blueIn                  =   0;
    }
    if (blueIn > 255) {
        blueIn                  =   255;
    }
    data[i]                     =   (redIn);
    data[i+1]                   =   (greenIn);
    data[i+2]                   =   (blueIn);
}
CGImageRef outImage             =   CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
myImage                         =   [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outImage];
CGImageRelease(outImage);

//Then blend it with a yellowish color
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myImage.size);
CGContextRef ctx                =   UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect area                     =   CGRectMake(0, 0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height);
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGContextClipToMask(ctx, area, myImage.CGImage);
UIColor *color                  =   [UIColor colorWithRed:248.0/255.0 green:254.0/255.0 blue:186.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]; //[UIColor colorWithRed:248.0/255.0 green:254.0/255.0 blue:186.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
[color set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, area);
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, myImage.CGImage);
myImage                         =   UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myImage.size);
ctx                             =   UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 area                           =   CGRectMake(0, 0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height);
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGContextClipToMask(ctx, area, myImage.CGImage);
color                           =   [UIColor colorWithRed:27.0/255.0 green:50.0/255.0 blue:224.0/255.0 alpha:0.2]; //[UIColor colorWithRed:248.0/255.0 green:254.0/255.0 blue:186.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
[color set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, area);
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeLighten);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, myImage.CGImage);
processedImage                  =   UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This might not work for you as is..Please play with this for your own requirement..Copied from memory, errors possible..

Comment: I have achieved all those effect's explained in that thread,by changing the RGB values.I have put my all efforts on this but I am not able to get this 3 filter.

Comment: The problem is image filter name like 'old' is not a standard like 'gray scale'..so it is very difficult to get information about its underlying logic...

Comment: Seeing your vintage picture, if you have time, just try this..
1. increase the contrast of the image a bit..
2. Draw a radial gradient over the image with light at the center and dark on the circumference..(To get the darkish edges of vintage image)..
3. Then blend it with a yellowish color...

Just play with it...That is what I did when I had a requirement like this..

Answer (score 0):

at first check out [Core Image documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/). Core image arrived with iOS 5.0 and is powerful image processing api.

Also you can use Quartz to draw image and over layer with different blending options (CGContextSetBlendMode) to achieve some nice effects.

If this techniques are not sufficient you can try changing color values pixel by pixel.
Try this [url](http://www.ipol.im/), maybe you find something for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My application don't support iOS 5.0. That why I am facing problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to determine the parameters of a RGB transformation. If you already have a tool to produce the "vintage", "old" and "nostalgia" effects, then you can process a sample image containing all the 256^3 RGB colors (like [this one](http://thomasinterestingblog.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/full-rgb-image/)), then observe, for example color channel by color channel to start simply, how the pixel values are modified. This may be enough to deduce the RGB transform function. And "old" will require a dark shadow on the border.